# When will be the extender function will get called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am newbie to knockout js. I want to implement dynamic validations for one observable. For that i want to use the extender function. But it is not calling. I have created the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Naidu526/uq72q/2/). 
My doubt is when it will be called.

The code is

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({logChange: "Sri" });
this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);

ko.extenders.logChange = function(target, option) {
    alert("log change function")
    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("subscribe function:  "+option + ": " + newValue);
    });
return target;
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Hello", "World")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is explicitly not stated in the documentation but

**any custom extender definition has to come before the first time you use it.**

So move the `ko.extenders.logChange` part outside of your `ViewModel` function:

```
ko.extenders.logChange = function(target, option) {
        alert("log change function")
    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("subscribe function:  "+option + ": " + newValue);
    });
    return target;
};

var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({logChange: "Sri" });
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName
        // depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when
        // evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxUXw/).

Comment: Simple and effective Thank you

Comment: Can we pass multiple values to the same extender function like i want to pass two names to the logChange() function

Comment: You can pass in an object as a the parameter of extender: `ko.observable(first).extend({logChange: {name1: "Sri", name2: "Sri2" }});` and in your extender you can access the properties with `option.name1` and `option.name2` http://jsfiddle.net/TMgm5/